# JUnit coverage showing red on MockitoAnnotations

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube

I have a Junit test class. When I ran test coverage in eclipse, I see all the test methods and the actual class is showing Green as covered but only the setUp method is showing in Red and also the Sonar test report is showing coverage as 0%. The same setUp() method is showing Green in other classes and also showing covered in Sonar. I am not sure what I am missing here.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
        public class AddServiceImplTest {
        
        @InjectMocks
        private AddServiceImpl addServiceImpl;
        
        @Mock
        private OtherClass otherClass;
        
        @Before
        public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }
    
    @Test
    public void test1() {
    ....
    }
```

Comment: Why would you be interested in the test coverage of your tests? Do you have tests for your tests?

Comment: make sure to exclude your test packages from Sonar.